# Are these two statements regarding Transfinite Recursion equivalent?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-recursion

I have two statements regarding Transfinite Recursion quoted below. It's clear that $S_1$ is the usual Transfinite Recursion Theorem.

---

> Let $V$ be the class of all sets, $\operatorname{Ord}$ be the class of all ordinals, and $G:V\to V$ be a class function.

$S1:$

> There exists a class function $F:\operatorname{Ord}\to V$ such that $F(\alpha)=G(F\restriction \alpha)$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$.

$S2:$

> There exists a class function $F:V\times\operatorname{Ord}\to V$ such that $F(z,\alpha)=G(z,F_z\restriction \alpha)$ for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$ and $z\in V$ where $F_z\restriction \alpha:=\{\langle\beta,F(z,\beta)\rangle\mid\beta<\alpha\}$.

---

In my textbook *Introduction to Set Theory* by Hrbacek and Jech, the authors do not utilize $S_1$ to prove $S_2$. Instead, they modify the proof of $S_1$ into a different proof of $S_2$.

I think it is possible to prove $S_1\implies S_2$, but I've tried to no avail since I can not handle the fact that $F$ in $S_1$ takes only $\alpha$ as input, while $F$ in $S_2$ takes both $z,\alpha$ as inputs.

**My question:**

1. Is $S_1$ related to $S_2$, i.e. $S_1\iff S_2$, or $S_1\implies S_2$, or $S_2\implies S_1$?
2. If $S_1\iff S_2$, or $S_1\implies S_2$, or $S_2\implies S_1$, please leave me some hints so that I can give it a try.

Thank you so much!

Comment: In S2, if $F$ is from the ordinals, how could you input $F(z,\alpha)$? Those are two variables and $z$ doesn't look like an ordinal. Also $G$ itself takes too many variables.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'm unable to understand what you meant by *$F$  is from the ordinals*, please elaborate more! Since $z\in V$, $z$ is not necessarily an ordinal. Of my understanding, $G:V\to V$ is a class function and $V$ is the class of all sets, so $G$ can take any set as its input, including such pair as $(z,F_z\restriction \alpha)$.

Comment: You wrote $F:Ord\to V$ in S2 too, while next line says $F(z, \alpha)$ like the domain of $F$ was rather $V\times Ord$. There's a similar problem with $G$, as it's currently written.

Comment: Thank you @Berci! That's my bad. I will edit my post. In $S_2$,  it should be $F:V\times\operatorname{Ord}\to V$. Can you elaborate more on what's wrong with $G$ in $S_2$?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with $G$ in $S_2$: the pair $\langle z,F_z\upharpoonright\alpha\rangle$ belongs to $V$.

Comment: Thank you @hartkp! I'm now relaxed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is reasonably clear that $S_2$ implies $S_1$; encode the $G$ you have for $S_1$ into a $G'$ for $S_2$, say by having $G'(z,x)=G(x)$ for all $x$ and $G'(y)=\emptyset$ if $y$ is not an ordered pair.
You get an $F'$ and $F'(\emptyset,\alpha)$ is the function you want.

The converse look more troublesome; for each individual set $z$ you can create a function $F_z$ as desired but you must realize that the Recursion Theorem is actually a theorem scheme: for every formula that descibes a function like $G$ there is another formula that describes a function like $F$. This means that you cannot talk about the assignment $z\mapsto F_z$ in order to combine the $F_z$s into one big $F$.
You have to look at the proof of $S_1$ and notice that you can sneak in the parameter $z$ in a uniform way and hence convert the proof of $S_1$ into a proof of $S_2$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @hartkp! I have supplemented your proof with more detail and posted it as an answer below so that I can truly understand your ideas. Could you please verify it?

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of @hartkp's answer, I present a proof with more detail. All credits are given to @hartkp.

---

> $S_2\implies S_1$

We define $G':V\to V$ as follows

$$G'(x)=\begin{cases}
G(f)&\text{if }x=(z,f)\text{ for some }z,f\in V\\\emptyset&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

By theorem $S_2$, there is a class function $F':V\times\operatorname{Ord}\to V$ such that $F'(z,\alpha)=G'(z,F'_z\restriction \alpha)$ for all $z\in V$ and for all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$. It follows that $F'(z,\alpha)=G(F'_z\restriction \alpha)$.

We define $F:\operatorname{Ord}\to V$ as follows $$F(\alpha)=F'(0,\alpha)\text{ for all }\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$$

We have $F'_0\restriction\alpha=\{\langle\beta,F'(0,\beta)\rangle\mid\beta<\alpha\}=\{\langle\beta,F(\beta)\rangle\mid\beta<\alpha\}=F\restriction\alpha$

Then $F(\alpha)=F'(0,\alpha)=G(F'_0\restriction\alpha)=G(F\restriction\alpha)$. This completes the proof.

Comment: That proof looks correct to me.

Comment: Thank you so much @hartkp! ^^